# How can I prove that some multiple of 1234 has (in its base 10 expansion) at most 1234 digits, each of which is either 5 or 0?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I really don't know how to approach this problem. It honestly seems like I could just say "Hey, look, I have a 0. If I multiply 1234 by 0, I get 0!" This answer proves that there is SOME multiple of 1234, it has at most 1234 digits and each digit is either 5 or 0. Boom, proven. I know that this isn't an appropriate answer though, so what would be?

Answer (score 1):

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $1234=2\times617$ divides $\dfrac{10^{616}-1}9\times50$.

Comment: I have looked at Fermat's little theorem, and I understand how you got 10^616 - 1. However, I do not understand where the 9 or 50 came from. As far as I can see, you only need the numerator to show that it is a multiple of 617.

Comment: multiplying by $\dfrac{50}9$ ensured that all the digits were either $5$ or $0$ rather than $9$ (and that it's a multiple of $2$)